# Discount on optional products or product bundles in odoo v17

Tags: bundle, e-commerce, discount, odoo-17

Is there a possibility that the customer pays less if he adds an optional product or can I create bundles or combinations in ecommerce in odoo v17?

So you buy a French fries for 4€ and if you add the optional product coke, you only pay 5€ instead of 6€, because the coke costs 2€.

This should also apply to all variants of the respective products, i.e. whether Coke Zero or normal and whether fries or sweet potato fries.

Is one of the two variants possible, or is there another possibility, except that I create coke as a variant of fries or create a new product fries + coke.

Hope anyone can help me. Thank You!

I try price lists, discounts. But nothing works only for these combinations. And not for every bundle. I've tried to create a discount, if one of these products is buy, and the price is over x€. But you can buy two pommes and get the discount.
The discount is for every combination